# BullseyeCoverage is either 0% or 100%. What am I missing?

Tags: c, linux, code-coverage

I need to find the coverage of a file in a project. This has to be done in Linux. Therefore, I made a script to see the coverage. Is there something I am missing? I am new at this. I searched for others with the same problems and their solutions don't work for me. The script looks like this:

```
export COVLM=$HOME/BullseyeLicense/BullseyeCoverageLicenseManagerUbuntu 
export PATH=/PROJ/..../bin:$PATH   
export BULLSEYE_PATH=/usr/bin
export PATH 

set COVFILE=/home/.../test.cov
export COVFILE=/home/.../test.cov

set COVDIR=/home/.../module_test
export COVDIR=coverage

cov01 -1


cd /home/.../src
. ./build_all.sh

CoverageBrowser &

cov01 -0
```